# Why are some attributes in .xlsx sheet not showing up in my dataframe created in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have imported Canada.xlsx file from my pc to `df_can` dataframe in Jupyter notebook. However some important attributes of xlsx file like 'OdName' are not visible. Also the data in the xlsx file starts with the country "Afghanistan" whereas my `df_can` dataframe starts with North-America.

Following is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df_can = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\datasets\\UN_MigFlow_A_to_E\\Canada.xlsx', sheet_name='Canada by Citizenship', skiprows=range(20), skip_footer=2 )
df_can.head()
```

I searched the internet but couldn't find any solution to both the problems. I also tried modifying the data-sheet in xlsx file itself by clearing the top 20 unwanted rows, but that didn't work either.

I am attaching the image of Canada.xlsx (i.e. expected outcome) and the url is

url:https://www.un.org/en/development/desa/population/migration/data/empirical2/migrationflows.asp (incase anyone's interested)

[image: Canada.xlsx]

The actual output is a data frame starting with North America and missing important attributes like 'OdName'. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem was not in the dataset, rather the code which I am following as a part of online course. Many of the codes are outdated and not upto the mark. Here's the correct code:

```
df_can = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\datasets\\UN_MigFlow_A_to_E\\Canada.xlsx', 'Canada by Citizenship', skiprows=range(20), skip_footer=2 )
df_can.head()
```

I was by mistake selecteing the other sheet and hence the data was not what I expected to be initially. Also all the attributes are now present.